# Ordering multiple cards of the same type same product id and same same vendor id in modprobe.conf

Tags: linux, kernel, asterisk, proc, pbx

We have two te435 cards with same vendor id, same product id and same type.
The problem which we are facing is, that it is not able to provide different modprobe options to two different cards.

```
# lspci
0c:00.0 Network controller: Digium, Inc. Device 800e (rev 01)
0e:00.0 Network controller: Digium, Inc. Device 800e (rev 01)

# lspci -n
0c:00.0 0280: d161:800e (rev 01)
0e:00.0 0280: d161:800e (rev 01)
```

We tried to index cards but that did not work for us.

```
 # modprobe wcte43x default_linemode=t1 index=0
 # modprobe wcte43x default_linemode=e1 index=1
```

Is there any way we can order cards in modprobe, so that multiple cards with same product id, vendor id can be enabled with different options in modprobe

Answer (score 0):

I think you not understand what is gooing on.

Modprobe line is list of options for module(in this case wcte43x), used at time when kernel loads this module.

You have ONE kernel and ONE load action, so you have no any way load TWO different sets of argument for that.

If you need different set, you have following options

1) change module itself to support different arguments based on pci-address(i think this is simplest method)

2) Create enother module with same functionality(and same source code) and load it for other card. Main problem here - you should force load other module for other card, which is problematic

Please also note, most of cards have jumper which change e1/t1 and ignore default_linemode.